# How can I print variables from the following for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import numpy as np

def initialize_parameters(n, L):
    for i in range(0, L):
      globals()['W%s' % i] = np.random.randn(n[i], n[i-1]) * 0.01

n = [2, 3, 1]
L = 3
initialize_parameters(n, L)
print(W0, '\n', W1, '\n', W2)
```

Instead of writing W0, W1, etc. in the last print function, I want a print function to print all Ws

Comment: Why not make ``W`` a list? That solves both the need to use ``globals`` and the complication of printing them all.

Comment: I know it probably looks stupid, but i'm just a beginner :( Can you please write me the list version of the code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know it probably looks stupid, but i'm just a beginner :( Can you please write me the list version of the code? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked how to turn this into a list I will go through it step by step.

In python a list is a set of objects surrounded with square brackets (e.g. `n` in your code is a list). Knowing this we can simply change your function like this to create a list and then add new values to it with the append function:

```
def initialize_parameters(n, L):
    a_list = []
    for i in range(0, L):
      a_list.append(np.random.randn(n[i], n[i-1]) * 0.01)
```

However as we are no longer using global variables there are a couple of other things we have to do to make this list accessible.

Firstly we need to tell the function to `return` the list:

```
def initialize_parameters(n, L):
    a_list = []
    for i in range(0, L):
      a_list.append(np.random.randn(n[i], n[i-1]) * 0.01)
    return a_list
```

Secondly when we call this function we have to assign it to a new variable:

```
list_of_Ws = initialize_parameters(n, L)
```

Now all you have to do is `print(list_of_Ws)` and you will see all of the values or `print(list_of_Ws[0])` for the first value, etc. for the rest of the values.

Comment: thank youuuuuu. there is just one last problem: it prints every elemet in the list like: [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5])].... how can i get rid of that array? i want each element of the list to be a matrix/vector

Comment: no, sorry, it works just fine. thank you, thank you, thank youuuuu

Comment: Ah that's because it is a numpy array. To change that you just have to add `.tolist()` at the end of the append statement:
`a_list.append((np.random.randn(n[i], n[i-1]) * 0.01).tolist())`

Answer (score -1):

You could theoretically iterate over `globals()` and output the value:

```py
for g in list(globals()):
    if g.startswith("W"):
        print(globals()[g])
```

But as @MisterMiyagi wrote in the comment, I would store the values in a list, not in `globals()`.

Comment: I know it probably looks stupid, but i'm just a beginner :( Can you please write me the list version of the code?